# Pass Array to Recursive Function While Modifying It C++

Tags: c++, arrays, function, c++11, recursion

I have a recursive function that takes a **2D array** as a parameter in C++. The contents of this 2D array are to be unique among all recursive calls of this function.

I would like to modify this array each time before I make the recursive call. How can I do this without modifying the array for both of the 2 recursive calls, just for the current call?

Here is what I am trying to accomplish:

```
void foo(int a[10][10]) {
  // imagine base case above
  // modify array, i.e. set a[2][2] to '5'
  foo(a);
  // modify array i.e. set a[2][2] to '3'
  foo(a);
}
```

I tried the following, which resulted in a compiler error:

```
void foo(int a[10][10]) {
  // imagine base case above
  foo(a[2][2] = 5);
  foo(a[2][2] = 3);
}
```

The idea is that I want the array to be **independent among recursive calls**, for example, I don't want the set `a[2][2] = 5` to apply to the next recursive call. I want that array modification to be "reverted", in a sense, before I apply the next modification (change).

This is easy to accomplish if I were just passing an `int` as an argument. For example, I could do:

```
void foo(int a) {
  // imagine base case above
  // increase a by 1
  foo(a + 1);
  // decrease a by 4
  foo(a - 4);
}
```

You can see here how easy it is to make the modifications without affecting the following recursive call.

My question here is how I can make changes along the same lines with an **array**.

Comment: So what you really want is to pass the array *by value*, so each recursive call have its own private copy that it can modify as it pleases, and when the recursive call returns the original array is unmodified? Then I suggest you look into [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) (or [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)) instead, as those will be much easier to pass by value.

Comment: As for the modification bit, perhaps add an argument which is a function to call to do the modification you want (which you could pass as a [lambda](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda)).

Comment: Could you please provide an example using `std::array` or `std::vector`? Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you're asking, but it seems you could do `void foo(int a[10][10]) { a[2][2] = 5; foo(a); a[2][2] = 3; foo(a); }`

Comment: @coder_jam: Your example is indeed not the best, as you change the same element, so cigien's proposal (with potential final restoration `const auto old = a[2][2], /*..*/; a[2][2] = old;`) does the job.

Comment: Yes, sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C-array cannot be copied, `std::array` can :)
So I would use `std::array`.

`a[2][2] = 5` mutates array, whereas `i - 4` doesn't mutate integer `i` (so nothing to discard in that case, contrary to `f(i -= 4)`).

there are no operator on array which allows easy customization,
we can create function or lambda for that:

```
// pass by value
std::array<std::array<int, 10>, 10>
mutated(std::array<std::array<int, 10>, 10> a, int x, int y, int value)
{
    a[x][y] = value;
    return a;
}

void foo(const std::array<std::array<int, 10>, 10>& a) {
  // imagine base case above
  // "modify" array, i.e. set a[2][2] to '5'
  foo(mutated(a, 2, 2, 5));
  // "modify" array i.e. set a[2][2] to '3'
  foo(mutated(a, 2, 2, 3));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call `foo(a + 1)` in your last example, you are not passing the original integer, but a copy of it, to the function. To achieve something similar with arrays, you would have to create a copy of the entire array, and then modify the copy before passing it to the function.

Example

```
void foo(int a[10][10]) {
  // Create two copies of a
  // We cannot simply do 'int b[10][10] = a;', because that would make 
  // b point to the same memory region as a.
  int b[10][10] = {0};
  int c[10][10] = {0};
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; ++j) {
      b[i][j] = a[i][j];
      c[i][j] = a[i][j];
    }
  }

  // Now that we have two copies of a, we can modify them separately
  // and pass the mto the functions

  // modify array, i.e. set [2][2] to '5'
  b[2][2] = 5;
  foo(b);
  // modify array i.e. set [2][2] to '3'
  c[2][2] = 3;
  foo(c);
```

This function would eat memory fast, since it leads to infinite recursion and creates two new 100-element arrays for each function call. The manual copying of `a` could also be done using `memcpy`, but I wrote it out as a nested for loop for clarity.